# Adding values to a Row ItemArray

Tags: c#

I am using some DataRow and with it, some ItemArray.

I know how to get the value into a ItemArray, but I don't know how to set values, when I create a new Row.

So I tried this :

```
                    DataRow newRow = vDsMod.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    newRow.ItemArray[0] = "".ToArray();
                    newRow.ItemArray[1] = "".ToArray();
                    newRow.ItemArray[2] = "Employee".ToArray();
                    newRow.ItemArray[3] = "".ToArray();
                    vDsMod.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Or

```
                    DataRow newRow = vDsMod.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    newRow.ItemArray.SetValue("", 0);
                    newRow.ItemArray.SetValue("", 1);
                    newRow.ItemArray.SetValue("Employee", 2);
                    newRow.ItemArray.SetValue("", 3);
                    vDsMod.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
```

But I only got empty fields in the ItemArray.
The value 0,1,3 can be empty, and as the ItemArray of the other lines has a lenght of 4, I also set 4 values.

How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ItemArray` returns an `object[]` which includes all fields. By accessing it via index here:

```
newRow.ItemArray[0] = "".ToArray();
```

you are accessing a single field and asigning a new value. But you're assigning a `char[]` because you use `String.ToArray()`, that is pointless.

Instead i would use the strongly typed `SetField` method which also support nullable types:

```
DataRow newRow = vDsMod.Tables[0].Rows.Add();
newRow.SetField(0, ""); 
newRow.SetField(1, ""); 
newRow.SetField(2, "Employee"); 
newRow.SetField(3, "");
```

With `Rows.Add();` the `DataRow` is already added. It's a matter of taste whether to use `DataTable.NewRow()` and add it later manually or `DataTable.Rows.Add()`.

Comment: Indeed this works. For the Row.Add(), it's a matter of taste, I understand, but if (maybe one day) forgot and do the two lines that add. It will not add the row two times?

Comment: @Zaphod: if you'd try to addd this row via `Rows.Add(newRow)` you would get an exception that this row already belongs to the table. So it's not possible to add it twice mistakenly.

Answer (score 1):

You can go as below ..

```
   DataRow relation;
     // Declare the array variable. 
    object [] rowArray = new object[2];
   for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
      rowArray[0]=null;
       rowArray[1]= "item " + i;
      relation = dt.NewRow();
      relation.ItemArray = rowArray;
      dt.Rows.Add(relation);
    }
```

I hope it will help you
Yeah it is on microsoft help. But according to your question you seems you didn't search a litle bit you just pposted the question. You want to know just how to initialize the ItemArray (As much i could understand) and you can find a lot of examples related to this.

Comment: Already found this with a search on google, and don't found it clear, and don't know if it fit my question.